# car insurance - 2 cars, can I have 2 separate NCD

Tags: united-kingdom, car, car-insurance

I know that I cannot use **No Claims Discount** on the **second car** but my question will be a little bit different.
I build 4 years NCB in last 4 years. But there was a moment when I bought second car. When I insured it I couldn't use NCB so second car had 0 NCB. After a year I sold a car and I got from the company 1 year NCB.
Now again I have 2 cars.
Can I use 4 years NCB for my main car and 1 NCB for second car?
In theory I should, this is separate thing.
Or I cannot?

thx!

Comment: There are a lot more factors we'd need to know before this can be answered. Are you the only person on both insurance policies? Are both cars insured with the same firm?

Comment: i'm the main driver on both policies [my wife is a second]. I do not have a firm.

Comment: No, I mean, are they both insured with Direct Line or Admiral or Churchill or whoever, or is one insured with Direct Line and the other with Admiral (etc.)

Comment: I'm sorry. Yes one firm AXA.

Answer (score 3):

That sounds OK, where you have two separately built up lots of NCD,. You can choose what to use, as long as you don't use one NCD on two cars.

Be careful as each company has policies on how gaps affect NCD, I'm not sure they are consistent across the industry. For example [Direct Line](http://faqs.directline.com/help/car-insurance/proof-ncd) requires the NCD to be less than two years old, so if you don't use it you lose it, others might have shorter limits.

Answer (score 1):

Most companies typically ignore NCD if they've gone unused for more than two years.

However its worth noting that some let you combine your NCD, I have two cars insured under my name and transferred my NCD from one car to the other so i don't loose them.

Doing this I've managed to get 5 years NCD on one car even though i am only 21.